# MATLAB is rounding off to nearest integer

Tags: matlab, floating-point, integer, precision

I have a `1x50000` size matrix `v` and I want to convert it to zero mean and unit variance:

```
x = ((v-mean(v))/std2(v));
```

But instead of giving me exact floating point values MATLAB is converting it to nearest integers. Please help me in getting the exact values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check the data type](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-type-identification.html) for `v`. I'm sure it's an [integer type](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html), using integer arithmetic, which is why the result is an integer. You need to convert it to a [floating point type](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html) to perform floating point operations on it:

```
v = double(v);              % Convert v to a double-precision float
x = ((v-mean(v))/std2(v));  % Result is now a double as well
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot